# Google structured data error: "All values provided for http://www.example.com/ must have the same domain."

Tags: google-search, schema.org, json-ld, google-rich-snippets

I want to add [Corporate Contacts](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/corporate-contacts) in Google Search. I test the following code in [Google's Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/), but it threw this error:

[image: Google SDTT: 1 error]

> `https://coda-resume.herokuapp.com/` (All values provided for `http://www.example.com/` must have the same domain.)

Here is the JSON-LD:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Organization",
  "url": "https://coda-resume.herokuapp.com/",
  "logo": "http://www.example.com/logo.png",
  "contactPoint": [{
    "@type": "ContactPoint",
    "telephone": "+1-401-555-1212",
    "contactType": "customer service"
  }]
}
</script>
```

(I put this in the `head` element.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google SDTT error: "All values provided for http://www.example.com/ must have the same domain."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40279203/google-sdtt-error-all-values-provided-for-http-www-example-com-must-have-th)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is likely a bug in Google’s Structured Data Testing Tool.

(When removing the `contactPoint` property, the tool no longer reports an error, although the snippet still contains the same `url` value.)

See [DieterDP’s answer in a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40381592/1591669).

Comment: It seems a bug. I thought I don't have this error one month age.

Comment: BTW, so I only need to add this `JSON-LD`, google search can help me to add information when people search my website?

Comment: I think Google’s SDTT throws this error only since a few weeks; they probably changed something, which had this side effect. -- I don’t understand your second comment. If this is really bug, you don’t have to do anything. Google will hopefully fix their SDTT at some point.

Comment: Oh, I mean I've put this code in `head` element, should I do something else, so Google will display my company's card when people search my company.

Comment: @CodaChang: If that’s what Google documents on the page you linked to, yes, why not? If you stil have a questions about their rich result, you could ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks, I am just feeling a little bit confused about its policy.

Answer (score 3):

I get this error:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Organization",
  "Url": "http://www.your-company-site.com",
  "Logo": "http://www.example.com/logo.png",
  "ContactPoint": [{
    "@type": "ContactPoint",
    "Telephone": "+ 1-401-555-1212",
    "ContactType": "customer service"
  }]
}
</script>
```

If you use `https://www.thegioididong.com` for example:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Organization",
  "Url": "https://www.thegioididong.com/",
  "Logo": "https://www.thegioididong.com/logo.png",
  "ContactPoint": [{
    "@type": "ContactPoint",
    "Telephone": "+ 1-401-555-1212",
    "ContactType": "customer service"
  }]
}
</script>
```

You will get the following errors in the testing tool:

> https://www.thegioididong.com/ (All values ​​provided for https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/ must have the same domain.)

This happens because you the code is not on the web before checking.

Upload the code to the website, then check back in the [testing tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool). Now you won't get any more errors.

Answer (score 1):

i was thinking it's a bug and trying to found solution, but this is not a bug at least we can't aspect from Google this kind of small bug. Basically error is saying (All values provided for https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/ must have the same domain.) so it's mean Google Tester aspecting URL value is "https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/" so if you try this code with your information just keep remain URL value as it is, you will find it working and 0 error.

```
 <script type='application/ld+json'> {"@context": "http://www.schema.org","@type": "Organization","name": "Your Company Name","url": "https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/","logo": "https://cdn.com/cms/assets/companylogo.svg","contactPoint": {"@type": "ContactPoint","telephone": "+90 00 000 00","contactType": "Customer Service"}}</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignore error at the Development level, 
On Live Production it works fine,
may be because, Google’s Structured Data Testing Tool consider Live Domain

Answer (score -1):

I've just realized that the error comes from the `@context` property.

Try changing "http://schema.org" to your site's URL, Google stops showing that error, and yes! That's WRONG! What characterizes a bug in the Google Tool!

Comment: While it might resolve the error, this is incorrect. The schema.org reference gives information on the keys in the rest of the script.