# Error: All values provided for http://www.example.com/, must have the same domain

Tags: html

I was testing the following code in [Google's Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/), but it threw this error:

> All values provided for http://www.example.com/, must have the same domain.

Why is it saying this? My domain name is the same as the website.

```
<div itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization" itemscope>
    <meta itemprop="name" content="exemple" />
    <meta itemprop="telephone" content="085 4014677" />
    <link itemprop="sameAs" href="https://twitter.com/exemple" />
    <link itemprop="url" href="https://www.exemple.nl/" />
    <div itemprop="address" itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress" itemscope>
        <meta itemprop="postalCode" content="exemple" />
        <meta itemprop="addressLocality" content="exmple" />
        <meta itemprop="streetAddress" content="exemple" />
    </div>
    <div itemprop="contactPoint" itemtype="http://schema.org/ContactPoint" itemscope>
        <meta itemprop="telephone" content="+31 005 400 40 70" />
        <meta itemprop="contactType" content="customer service" />
        <meta itemprop="email" content="info@exemple.nl" />
        <div itemprop="hoursAvailable" itemtype="http://schema.org/OpeningHoursSpecification" itemscope>
            <meta itemprop="opens" content="9:00" />
            <meta itemprop="closes" content="17:30" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: maybe helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40399076/google-structured-data-error-all-values-provided-for-http-www-example-com-m

Comment: I've read that post. I don't have a contactPoint in my code..

Comment: You have! On line 11. Maybe a mistake? I think a closing Tag is missing too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google structured data error: "All values provided for http://www.example.com/ must have the same domain."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40399076/google-structured-data-error-all-values-provided-for-http-www-example-com-m)