# microdata type NewsArticle in index page and double content Organization

Tags: seo, schema.org, microdata

My question about double content.

In my index page (home page) i have news block. Each news article refers to the `id="microdataCompany" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization"`

Part of my code:

```
<section itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ItemList">
        <div class="news">
            <h2 itemprop="name">News</h2>
            <article class="first-news">
                <ul>
                    <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/NewsArticle" itemref="microdataCompany">
                        <meta itemprop="position" content="1" />
                        <a href="http://example.com/" title="Первая статья" itemprop="mainEntityOfPage url">
                            <span>Date Published:<span itemprop="datePublished"> 2017-02-14</span>
                            <br>Date: <span itemprop="dateModified">2017-02-14</span><em itemprop="headline"><br>New article</em></span>
                        </a>
                        <p itemprop="description">Lorein ipsum Lorein ipsum Lorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsum Lorein ipsum Lorein ipsum Lorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsum Lorein ipsum Lorein ipsum Lorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsum</p>
                        <h4 itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Person"> Autor: <span itemprop="name">Black Jack</span></h4>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </article>
            <article class="second-news">
                <ul>
                    <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/NewsArticle" itemref="microdataCompany">
                        <meta itemprop="position" content="1" />
                        <a href="http://example.com/" title="Первая статья" itemprop="mainEntityOfPage url">
                            <span>Date Published:<span itemprop="datePublished"> 2017-02-14</span>
                            <br>Date: <span itemprop="dateModified">2017-02-14</span><em itemprop="headline"><br>New article</em></span>
                        </a>
                        <p itemprop="description">Lorein ipsum Lorein ipsum Lorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsum Lorein ipsum Lorein ipsum Lorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsum Lorein ipsum Lorein ipsum Lorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsum</p>
                        <h4 itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Person"> Autor: <span itemprop="name">Black Jack</span></h4>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </article>
            <article class="third-news">
                <ul>
                    <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/NewsArticle" itemref="microdataCompany">
                        <meta itemprop="position" content="1" />
                        <a href="http://example.com/" title="Первая статья" itemprop="mainEntityOfPage url">
                            <span>Date Published:<span itemprop="datePublished"> 2017-02-14</span>
                            <br>Date: <span itemprop="dateModified">2017-02-14</span><em itemprop="headline"><br>New article</em></span>
                        </a>
                        <p itemprop="description">Lorein ipsum Lorein ipsum Lorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsum Lorein ipsum Lorein ipsum Lorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsum Lorein ipsum Lorein ipsum Lorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsumLorein ipsum</p>
                        <h4 itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Person"> Autor: <span itemprop="name">Black Jack</span></h4>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </article>
        </div>
    </section>
    <aside class="aside-1" itemprop="publisher" id="microdataCompany" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
        <div class="service" itemprop="makesOffer" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
            <ul>
                <li><a itemprop="url" href="/services/something/">something</a></li>
                <li><a itemprop="url" href="/services/something/">something</a></li>
                <li><a itemprop="url" href="/services/something/">something</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="contacts">
            <a itemprop="url" href="http://example.com">
                <div itemprop="name">Company</div>
            </a>
            <hr>
            <div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
                <strong>Adress: </strong>
                <span itemprop="addressCountry">Country</span>,
                <span itemprop="addressRegion">Region</span>,
                <span itemprop="addressLocality">City</span>,
                <span itemprop="streetAddress">street</span>.
                <br>Postal index:
                <span itemprop="postalCode">429384828</span>
                <br>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <strong>telephone : </strong><span itemprop="telephone"> +3 (678) 145-44-55 </span>
            <br>
            <b>Email : </b><span itemprop="email"><a href="mailto:aili@mail.com">maili@mail.com</a></span>
            <br>
            <strong>Founding: </strong><span itemprop="foundingDate"> 2000-01-01</span>
            <br>
        </div>
    </aside>
```

In google mirodata validator we have double content (description Organization)

[Image from google testing microdata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyNvD.png)

It is not good for SEO. Because google bot say thats its spam. 
What do i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, [duplicate content](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplicate_content) is something different ("content that appears **on more than one web page**").

In your case, you have one `Organization` item that gets referenced as `publisher` of three `NewsArticle` items. This is the perfect solution for such a case.

The output in the SDTT shows you that Google understands it correctly. It lists the three `NewsArticle` items, and each `NewsArticle` has the `Organization` as `publisher`. In some cases, each news item might have a different organization as publisher, but in your case, it’s the same organization. That is, of course, not problematic: it *is* the same organization, so this should be represented in the structured data, too.

Comment: Dankeschön!!! You are the best!!! I asked to you one more the question in github (schema) (about "hasPart")

Comment: @ConstantinYakovlev: Не за что! ;) Regarding the other question: I think GitHub is not the right place for this. If you have a specific question about Schema.org, you can ask here. If you have a SEO-related question about Schema.org, you can ask on [webmasters.se]. If you want a markup review, you can ask on [codereview.se].

Comment: Ich verstanden!)) About news-posting in home page. Why a newspaper  The Guardian not used  (https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool#url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.theguardian.com%2Finternational)  NewsArticle for news-posting?  Maybe it's a better version for news-posting?

Comment: @ConstantinYakovlev: No idea why they don’t use it. If they want to keep `ListItem` (in my opinion, it’s not really needed), they could even use both types together: `itemtype="http://schema.org/NewsArticle http://schema.org/ListItem"`

Comment: And one more question!)  How to fix this mistake in google testing tools microdata: 
**All url values ​​must belong to the same domain.**
Because all my urls has one domain name

Comment: @ConstantinYakovlev: As far as I know, this is [likely another bug](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40400319/1591669) in Google’s testing tool. Even Google’s own examples get this error. Don’t worry about it.

Comment: Thank you so much!