# Schema Data for a School

Tags: schema.org, json-ld, structured-data

### Best Schema Practiced for School with Subdivisions

I am interested in best SEO practices for creating schema markup for a [School](https://schema.org/School) that has subdivisions: [Preschool](https://schema.org/Preschool), [ElementarySchool](https://schema.org/ElementarySchool), [MiddleSchool](https://schema.org/MiddleSchool), and [HighSchool](https://schema.org/HighSchool). My plan initially is to create JSON-LD for each of the division pages and the home page.

My questions are:

1. is this a good method of doing this and in line with best schema practices?
2. When using schema, what is the best method of associating a subdivision of a school with the school?
3. Would it be appropriate to use the schema [contactPoint](https://schema.org/contactPoint) to mark up each of the names and phone numbers on the contact page?
4. Are there any opportunities I should take advantage of or pitfalls I should avoid?

I have included JSON-LD code for what I'm thinking the code for some of these pages might look like.

### Home Page:

```
<script type='application/ld+json'>
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "School",
  "address": {
    "@type": "PostalAddress",
    "addressCountry": "Country",
    "addressLocality": "City",
    "addressRegion": "State",
    "postalCode": "12345",
    "streetAddress": "123 School St",
    "telephone": "+15432190100",
    "description": "This is a very good school"
  },
  "areaServed": "City",
  "name": "School",
  "url": "https://www.school.edu",
  "sameAs": [
    "https://www.facebook.com/school",
    "https://www.youtube.com/user/school",
    "http://twitter.com/school",
    "https://www.instagram.com/school/"
  ]
}
</script>
```

### Preschool Page

**Note:** The phone number and name are different but the address is the same. Would this be duplicate or spammy in Google's eyes?

```
<!--Preschool-->
<script type='application/ld+json'>
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Preschool",
  "address": {
    "@type": "PostalAddress",
    "addressCountry": "Country",
    "addressLocality": "City",
    "addressRegion": "State",
    "postalCode": "12345",
    "streetAddress": "123 School St",
    "telephone": "+15432190101",
    "description": "School has a very good preschool"
  },
  "areaServed": "City",
  "name": "School - Preschool",
  "url": "https://www.school.edu/preschool",
  "parentOrganization": {
    "@type": "School",
    "name": "School"
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried to provide you the best solution with all possibilities.

Let's clear your doubts first.

**Ans1:** You are going in the right direction though structure needs to be modified as shown in below code.

**Ans2:** For implementing Subdivision, the best method is to use [Educational Organization Schema](http://schema.org/EducationalOrganization) which provides SubOrganization.

**Ans3:** You can check the use of contactPoint in your case in below given code.

**Ans4:** There aren't any pitfalls if you are doing that properly.

Below JSON-LD contains all the structure that you might require like **School, PreSchool, MiddleSchool** etc.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "EducationalOrganization",
  "name" : "School",
  "address": {
    "@type": "PostalAddress",
    "addressCountry": "IN",
    "addressLocality": "City",
    "addressRegion": "State",
    "postalCode": "000000",
    "streetAddress": "#310 Example",
    "telephone": "+15432190100",
    "description": "This is a very good school"
  },
  "areaServed": "City",
  "@id" : "http://www.example.com/homepage-url",
  "url": "http://www.example.com/",
  "logo": "http://www.example.com/images/logo.png",
  "email" : "example@example.com",
  "sameAs": [
    "https://www.facebook.com/example",
    "http://twitter.com/example",
    "https://www.instagram.com/example"
  ],
  "subOrganization" : [
    {
        "@type": "Preschool",
        "name" : "Preschool 1",     
        "telephone" : "+1-877-672-7777",
        "@id" : "http://www.example.com/preschool-1",
        "url": "http://www.example.com/preschool-1",    
        "address":{
          "@type":"PostalAddress",
          "streetAddress":"#310 Example",
          "addressLocality":"City",
          "addressRegion":"State",
          "postalCode":"000000",
          "addressCountry":"IN"
        },
        "contactPoint" : [
            { "@type" : "ContactPoint",
              "telephone" : "+1-877-746-0909",
              "contactType" : "Customer Service",
              "contactOption" : "TollFree",
              "areaServed" : "IN"
            } , 
            { "@type" : "ContactPoint",
              "telephone" : "+1-877-746-0606",
              "contactType" : "Bill Payment",
              "contactOption" : "TollFree",
              "areaServed" : "IN"
            } 
        ]   
    },
    {
        "@type": "Preschool",
        "name" : "Preschool 2",
        "telephone" : "+1-877-672-8888",
        "@id" : "http://www.example.com/preschool-2",
        "url": "http://www.example.com/preschool-2",
        "address":{
          "@type":"PostalAddress",
          "streetAddress":"#310 Example",
          "addressLocality":"City",
          "addressRegion":"State",
          "postalCode":"000000",
          "addressCountry":"IN"
        },
        "contactPoint" : [
            { "@type" : "ContactPoint",
              "telephone" : "+1-877-746-3030",
              "contactType" : "Customer Service",
              "contactOption" : "TollFree",
              "areaServed" : "IN"
            } , 
            { "@type" : "ContactPoint",
              "telephone" : "+1-877-746-2020",
              "contactType" : "Bill Payment",
              "contactOption" : "TollFree",
              "areaServed" : "IN"
            } 
        ]
    },
    {
        "@type": "MiddleSchool",
        "name" : "MiddleSchool 1",  
        "telephone" : "+1-877-672-9999",    
        "@id" : "http://www.example.com/middleschool-1",
        "url": "http://www.example.com/middleschool-1",
        "address":{
          "@type":"PostalAddress",
          "streetAddress":"#310 Example",
          "addressLocality":"City",
          "addressRegion":"State",
          "postalCode":"000000",
          "addressCountry":"IN"
        }  
    },
        {
        "@type": "MiddleSchool",
        "name" : "MiddleSchool 2",  
        "telephone" : "+1-877-672-0000",
        "@id" : "http://www.example.com/middleschool-2",
        "url": "http://www.example.com/middleschool-2",
        "address":{
          "@type":"PostalAddress",
          "streetAddress":"#310 Example",
          "addressLocality":"City",
          "addressRegion":"State",
          "postalCode":"000000",
          "addressCountry":"IN"
        }  
    }
  ]
}
</script>
```

The above code is also verified with Google Structured Data Testing Tool.
Attaching the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOdwP.png) for your reference.

Don't worry about "Uncategorized Error", it's likely a Bug in Google Schema Tool.
More info about that error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40399076/google-structured-data-error-all-values-provided-for-http-www-example-com-m).

Hope it works :)